# xset s timeout cycle does not stay set

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lock-screen, i3-window-manager

I'm running Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster) with Regolith (i3 window manager). I have been trying to set `xsecurelock` as the screen locker.

OK, tons of background now:

If you and add this line to `~/.config/regolith2/Xresources`:

```
i3-wm.program.lock: xsecurelock
```

Then manually activating the screenlock works, but the idle timeout still runs the Gnome Flashback locker. You can turn this off with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.gnome-flashback screensaver false
```

but now you don't have an idle timeout screen locker.

I have been trying to get around this will `xss-lock`. I start this by adding a file `~/.config/regolith2/i3/config.d/screenlock`:

```
exec --no-startup-id killall xss-lock ; xss-lock -n /usr/libexec/xsecurelock/dimmer -- xsecurelock
```

and changing the `Xresources` line to:

```
i3-wm.program.lock: xset s activate
```

Now manually activating the screenlock still works and if I type `xset s 5 0` then the screen locks correctly with `xsecurelock` in 5 seconds (I can't get the dimmer working but that's not the problem I'm working on right now).

**and now the actual problem:**

If I type `xset s 60 0` I get no idle timeout. If I type `xset s 60 0` then `xset q` then I can see the timeout and cycle as 60 and 0, but if I keep typing `xset q` then I see that about once a minute the timeout and cycle are reset to 0 and 0.

This happens even if I log in with "Ubuntu" as the window manager not "Regolith".

So, what is it that's resetting the idle timeout? Can I stop it? Am I going about this all wrong?